# Is function $f(x)$ same as floor function?

Tags: harmonic-numbers

Let
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{Im}\left( -\frac{2\lfloor n\rfloor}{\pi}H_{-x}^{\left( -\frac1{2\lfloor n \rfloor} \right)} \right)$$
where $H$ is harmonic number and $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$. I do not know much about harmonic numbers, but I am wondering if this function is same as floor function, i.e. is it true that $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$? I plotted the floor function and $f(x)$ for $n=1000$ and functions overlap. Is it just a coincidence or there is a proof that $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$?

**Edit**
Also, I noticed that $f(x)$ is continuous on whole interval $(0,\infty)$ only if $n$ doesn't approach $\infty$. At $n\to\infty$ this function isn't continuous on integer values of $x$. Can it be proved?

Comment: Which definition of $H$ are you using?

Comment: @Regret. I think there is only one definition of harmonic numbers. See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html).

Comment: But here the $H$ has negative subscript, not covered by the "one defintion" cited.

Comment: @GEdgar. It says that $H_n=\gamma+\psi_0(n+1)$ for all real $n$ and digamma function is definad for all real numbers.

Comment: When I plot your function for $n=1000$, it looks nothing like $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: @GEdgar. What program you have used to plot this function? I know only two programs which can plot harmonic number functions for all complex number. These programs are Mathematica and Maple. [This](http://s4.postimg.org/7nqnhudnx/zzzzzzzzzz.png) is my plot in Mathematica. As you can see, only difference is that $f(x)$ is continuous, but it is only beacuse $n$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

OK, from the Mathematica code shown, I see that I had misinterpreted
$H_{-x}^{(r)}$ as a power of $H_{-x}$.  But in fact it is a two-argument generalized Harmonic number, denoted $H_{-x,r}$ on the Mathworld page.

..............

According to Maple, near $r=0$ we have
$$
H_{k,r} = k - \big(\ln\Gamma(k+1)\big)r+O(r^2)\qquad\text{ as } r \to 0
$$
Therefore, for any $x > 0$ we have
$$
\frac{-2n}{\pi}H_{-x,{-1/(2n)}} = \frac{-2n}{\pi}\left(-x+\ln\Gamma(-x+1)\frac{-1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)
$$
The $-x$ term is real, so we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{-2n}{\pi}H_{-x,{-1/(2n)}}\right)
=\frac{-1}{\pi}\mathrm{Im}\big(\ln\Gamma(-x+1)\big)
$$
So the question is whether this is $\lfloor x \rfloor$.  It no longer has anything to do with harmonic numbers.  It will follow from the functional equation for $\Gamma$.